# Input Parsing in C & deciding where to forward

Tags: c, parsing, io

So I have the following project i need to work on for school. It involves a server/client communicating where the client sends requests to the server to get certain information. The server gets the req, parses it, and then sends a response based on the type of the request. For example:

```
GET /apple/fn/tom/ln/sawyer/a/25/id/1234 : This is a request to get the info for the following person who works at the Apple company (/apple):
fn (first name): Tom
ln (last name): Sawyer
a (age): 25
id (ID): 1234
```

Now the server should accept input, parse it, and return the information requested from its own database. implementing the server/client is not an issue. I need to know the best way to implement the algorithm to deal with input since not all requests would look like the one above. Other examples of requests:

```
GET /apple/i: This should return info about Apple company (i.e. address, phone number)
GET /apple/e: return number of employees in Apple company
GET /apple/e/id/1234: return info of employee in Apple company with the following id=1234 (which in our example would be Tom Sawyer) i.e. return first name, last name, age, address.
GET /apple/fn/tom/ln/sawyer/a/25/id/1234 : discussed above
SET /apple/fn/tom/ln/sawyer/a/25/id/5678 : update id of this employee to 5678
SET /apple/fn/tom/ln/sawyer/a/23 : update age of this employee to 23
```

...

I will have to implement different structs for req/response (i.e. a struct for req and another for response) as well as a different function for each of the different request/responses. BUT what is the best way to deal with parsing input && decide which function to send it to? I was told to look into using a parser-generator like Bison but to my understanding this would only help parse the input and break it up into pieces which is not that hard for me since I know I always have the "/" between fields so I can use the function:

```
strtok( input, "/" );
```

So main issue I have is how to decide where to send each request. So Assuming I have the following functions:

```
struct GetEmployeeInfoReq
{
   char *fn;
   char *ln;
   int age;
};
struct GetEmployeeInfoResp
{
   int house_num;
   int street_num;
   char *street_name;
   char * postal_code;
   int years_worked_here;
};
void GetEmployeeInfo( struct GetEmployeeInfoResp *resp, struct GetEmployeeInfoReq *req );

struct GetCompanyInfoReq
{
  ...
}
struct GetCompanyInfoResp
{
  ...
}
void GetCompanyInfo( struct GetCompanyInfoResp *resp, struct GetCompanyInfoReq *req );
```

Now I know that to call the first function I need the following request:

```
GET /apple/fn/tom/ln/sawyer/a/25/id/1234
```

and to call 2nd function I need the following:

```
GET /apple/i
```

My question is how to get this done? Off the top of my mind I'm thinking defining a variable for each possible field in the input req and using that so if this is my request:

```
GET /apple/e/id/1234
```

then I would have the following values defined and set to true:

```
bool is_apple = true;
bool is_employee = true;
bool is_id = true;
```

After I know that this request is:

```
GET /apple/e/id/<id_num>
```

AND NOT

```
GET /apple/e
```

so i can send it to the proper function.
Is this the correct approach as I'm lost on how to tackle this issue.

Thanks,

Comment: Yes, what was told to you is correct, including `strtok()` (with mutable input, needless to mention), but do you have a specific problem at hand?

Comment: strtok() is a terrible function, it doesn't allow "empty" segments to be isolated from the string; it would fail for instance on `/apple/fn//ln/sawyer/a/25/id/1234` (first name is empty here)

Comment: @SouravGhosh I added more details in the question description.

Comment: @wildplasser Lets assume that no field is allowed to be empty

Comment: The best way to parse the string is to manually loop through it, inspecting every character (compare it to {' ', '/', '\n', '\0'}, or use strcspn() ) and take appropiate action.

Comment: an alternative would be to use YACC/Bison but that requires forming a grammar - unless this gets answered by the weekend i'll post alot of code that should help you get it done by the end of the weekend.

Comment: @wildplasser that is what `strsep` is for. (it will allow empty fields) or just walk a pair of pointers down the string and manually separate the fields....

Comment: JJ, in order to know which function to call, you need *criteria* to evaluate to make the choice. Take `/apple/fn/tom/ln/sawyer/a/25/id/1234`. Other than `apple` and `id`, the remainder seem to be `key/value` pairs (e.g. `fn/tom`, `ln/sawyer`, `a/25`). Do you have a specification for what `/the/format/is/supposed/to/be`? I ask because if there is a defined format, then your choice can be a simple test of the `keys`. If you have an array of *company* `keys` and and array of *employee* `keys`, after parsing, you check which you have an know where to send the request. Are the keys known?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get yourself a large piece of paper and make a diagram about the logic to get a grammar (not actually neede here, you could just parse it, but being a school assignment I assume that it is meant to be build up upon).

Some observations

- every input starts with a `/`
- every entry ends with a `/` except the last one
- entries consist of characters and/or digits
- empty entries gets you in trouble if you insist on using `strtok` (thanks to wildplasser, I missed that)
- order matters?

Entries are

- either key (one entry) or key/value (two consecutive entries).
  In other words: the may or may not have an argument

Entries with a meaning

- first entry is the company name (what do you do if that's all? Check assignment)
- next entry is either

  - `i` print company info
  - `e`
  - without arguments: print #employees
  - with argument: print information about argument, argument must be correct
  - `fn` first name as a key, must have a value because of `strtok`, argument must be  a string
  - `ln` last name as a key, must have a value because of `strtok`, argument must be  a string
  - `id` id as a key, must have a value because of `strtok`, argument must be a string of digits (an integer so to say but it is still a string at that point) only
  - `a` age as a key, must have a value because of `strtok`, argument must be a string of digits (an integer so to say but it is still a string at that point) only

Examples:

`/apple/e`

1. `/` start of input
2. `apple` company name. Must have an argument, so go on
3. `e` something with employers, my or may not have an argument so check.
4. `EOI` (end of input) that means that `e` has no arguments, so print the number of employees.

`/apple/id/134`

1. `/` start of input
2. `apple` company name. Must have an argument, so go on
3. `e` something with employers, my or may not have an argument so check.
4. `id` is a key and must have a value, that means we need an argument, so check
5. `1234` all digits which is correct value for `id`
6. `EOI` (end of input) no other things, so print the information you have about id-1234

`/apple/fn/tom/ln/sawyer/a/25/id/1234`

1. `/` start of input
2. `apple` company name. Must have an argument, so go on
3. `fn` is a key, must have a value, check
4. `tom` the value for `fn` must be a string which it is, safe
5. `ln` is a key, must have a value, check
6. `sawyer` the value for `ln` must be a string which it is, safe
7. `a` is a key, must have a value, check
8. `25` the value for `ln` must be a string of digits which it is, safe
9. `id` is a key, must have a value, check
10. `1234` the value for `ln` must be a string of digits which it is, safe
11. `EOI` (end of input). The key for the database entry seems to be the name `fn` and `ln`, so read the entry `tomsawyer` and check if any of `id` or `a` is different and change accordingly. If nothing is different: check your assignment.

It might be good idea to build a struct with all of the informations and fill it while parsing (where I wrote "safe"). You need two main functions `printIt(keys)` and `changeIt(key, value)`. Some things can be done immediately, like in my first example, some need further ado.

That's it, should be straightforward to implement.

**EDIT** a short example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// ALL CHECKS OMMITTED!

#define DELIMITER '/'

// should resemble a row from the DB
typedef struct company {
  char *comp_name;
  unsigned int num_empl;
  unsigned int empl_id;
  unsigned int empl_age;
  char *first_name;
  char *last_name;
} company;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  company *entries;
  char *input, *token;
  size_t ilen;

  if (argc < 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s stringtoparse \n", argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  // work on copy
  ilen = strlen(argv[1]);
  input = malloc(ilen + 1);
  strcpy(input, argv[1]);

  entries = malloc(sizeof(company));

  // skip first delimiter
  if (*input == DELIMITER) {
    input++;
    ilen--;
  }

  token = strtok(input, "/");
  if (token == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage : %s stringtoparse \n", argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  // first entry is the company name
  entries->comp_name = malloc(strlen(token));
  strcpy(entries->comp_name, token);

  // mark empty entries as empty
  entries->first_name = NULL;
  entries->last_name = NULL;
  entries->empl_age = -1;
  entries->empl_id = -1;
  // F(23)
  entries->num_empl = 28657;

  // only very small part of grammar implemented for simplicity
  for (;;) {
    token = strtok(NULL, "/");
    if (token == NULL) {
      break;
    }
    // "e"  [ "/" "id" "/" number <<EOF>> ]
    if (strcmp(token, "e") == 0) {
      token = strtok(NULL, "/");
      if (token == NULL) {
    puts("Info about number of employees wanted\n");
    // pure info, pull from DB (not impl.) and stop
    break;
      } else {
    if (strcmp(token, "id") != 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Only \"id\" allowed after \"e\" \n");
      // free all heap memory here
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    token = strtok(NULL, "/");
    if (token == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: \"id\" needs a number \n");
      // free all heap memory here
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // does not check if it really is a number, use strtol() in prod.
    entries->empl_id = atoi(token);
    printf("Info about employee with id %d wanted\n", entries->empl_id);
    // pure info, pull from DB (not impl.) and stop
    break;
      }
    }
    // "a" "/" number
    else if (strcmp(token, "a") == 0) {
      token = strtok(NULL, "/");
      if (token == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: \"a\" needs a number \n");
    // free all heap memory here
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
      // does not check if it actually is a number, use strtol() in prod.
      entries->empl_age = atoi(token);
      printf("Age given: %d\n", entries->empl_age);
    }
    // "id" "/" number
    else if (strcmp(token, "id") == 0) {
      token = strtok(NULL, "/");
      if (token == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: \"id\" needs a number \n");
    // free all heap memory here
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
      // does not check if it actually is a number, use strtol() in prod.
      entries->empl_id = atoi(token);
      printf("ID given: %d\n", entries->empl_id);
    }
    // "fn" "/" string
    else if (strcmp(token, "fn") == 0) {
      token = strtok(NULL, "/");
      if (token == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: \"fn\" needs a string \n");
    // free all heap memory here
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
      entries->first_name = malloc(strlen(token));
      strcpy(entries->first_name, token);
      printf("first name given: %s\n", entries->first_name);
    }
    // "ln" "/" string
    else if (strcmp(token, "ln") == 0) {
      token = strtok(NULL, "/");
      if (token == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: \"ln\" needs a string \n");
    // free all heap memory here
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
      entries->last_name = malloc(strlen(token));
      strcpy(entries->last_name, token);
      printf("last name given: %s\n", entries->last_name);
    } else {
      fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Unknown token \"%s\" \n", token);
      // free all heap memory here
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  }
  printf("\n\nEntries:\nCompany name: %s\nFirst name: %s\nLast name: %s\n",
     entries->comp_name, entries->first_name, entries->last_name);
  printf("Age: %d\nID: %d\nNumber of employees: %d\n",
     entries->empl_age, entries->empl_id, entries->num_empl);
  /*
   * At this state you have information about what is given (in "entries")
   * and what is wanted.
   * 
   * Connect to the DB.
   * 
   * If firstnamelastname is the DB-id and in the DB, you can check if
   * the given ID is the same as the one in the DB and change if not.
   * 
   * You can do the same for age.
   * 
   * If firstnamelastname is not in the DB but ID is given check if the
   * ID is in the DB, change firstname and/or lastname if necessary and
   * congratulate on the wedding (many other reasons are possible, please
   * check first or it might get really embarassing)
   */

  // free all heap memory here

  /* Disconnect from the DB */
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Compiled with:

```
gcc -g3 -std=c11 -W -Wall -pedantic jjadams.c -o jjadams
```

try with

```
./jjadams "/Apple/fn/Tom/ln/Sawyer/a/10/id/3628800"

./jjadams "/Apple/e"

./jjadams "/Apple/e/id/1234"

./jjadams "/Apple/e/1234"
```

Comment: As noted in the comments to the question, if there is the potential for an empty field (e.g. `/Apple/e/id//a/10`), then `strsep` provides the ability to tokenize the string while preserving the empty field. (good answer)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It's a school assignment according to the OP and I assumed the use of `strtok()` to be fixed. It is also not the first way I would have chosen, it i ssuch a simple grammar, a simple character-wise parse together with a bit of creative pointer juggling would have done it, but that's not something you can "sell" the teacher as your own idea. What I have thought about is to add a proper grammar but scrapped it because of the already overly long post.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there are no empty fields to deal with in this Q, but the `strsep` was for completeness in response to the complaint in the original comments. I thought your answer was good, I only mentioned it because I find a majority of those learning C haven't heard of it and don't know the distinction in use between `strtok` and `strsep` is the ability to handle empty fields.